# While loop, wrap items in a count in a separate div (index.php)

Tags: php, wordpress, while-loop

I have the following so far:

```
<?php $count = 0; while (have_posts()) : the_post(); $count++; ?>

                <?php if ($count < 5) : ?>
                    //four posts here, all them wrapped in one div, these will also have different markup
                    <?php the_title();?>



                <?php else : ?>
                   //remaining six posts here, all of them wrapped in one div, these will also have different markup
                    <?php the_title();?> blah
                    <?php the_excerpt();?>

                <?php endif; ?>


            <?php endwhile; ?>
```

I want to wrap the first 4 in a '`<div class="top"></div>`' and the bottom 6, I want all of them wrapped in a '`<div class="bottom"></div>`'

Any tips of how this can be done using the while loop would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below snippet.

```
<?php 
$count = 0;

while (have_posts()) : the_post(); $count++; 

    if ( $count == 1 ) echo '<div class="top">';
    if ( $count > 5 ) echo '</div><div class="bottom">';

    the_title();
    if ( $count > 5 ) the_excerpt();

endwhile;

echo "</div>"
?>
```

Comment: I think you need to change `the_excerpt();` line to `if ($count > 5) the_excerpt();` as the OP only wants the excerpt to appear in the second DIV

Comment: @Venkatraman, what I want to add html in those different loops, this doesn't allow for that huh?

Comment: if you want few more html in each condition you can follow <?php if ($count > 5) : ?> your html <?php endif; ?>

Answer (score 0):

This might help you.

```
        <?php $count = 0; while (have_posts()) : the_post(); $count++; ?>

            <?php if ($count < 5) : ?>
                //four posts here, all them wrapped in one div, these will also have different markup
               <div class="top">
                <?php the_title();?>
               </div>



            <?php else : ?>
               //remaining six posts here, all of them wrapped in one div, these will also have different markup
                <div class="bottom">
                <?php the_title();?> blah
                <?php the_excerpt();?>
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>


        <?php endwhile; ?>
```